# const is undefined within reduce method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

```
avgPrice(data) {
    const min_price = data.min_price,
    max_price = data.max_price;

    console.log(min_price) //has value

    let x = _.reduce(data.custom_pricing, (a, b) => {
        a.min_price = Math.min(a.min_price, b.min_price);
        a.max_price = Math.max(a.max_price, b.max_price);
    }, { min_price:min_price, max_price:max_price });
}
```

What's wrong with my code above? I got min_price is undefined error. But my const min_price has value when I do console.log.

Comment: Shouldn't `let x = reduce` be `let x = _.reduce`?

Comment: @Kinduser It's `_.reduce` not `Array.prototype.reduce`.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return from `reduce` (return `a` so it can be used for the next iteration).

```
let x = _.reduce(data.custom_pricing, (a, b) => {
    a.min_price = Math.min(a.min_price, b.min_price);
    a.max_price = Math.max(a.max_price, b.max_price);

    return a; //<<<<<
}, { min_price:min_price, max_price:max_price });
```

**No mutation:**

Although I don't see a reason why.

```
let x = _.reduce(data.custom_pricing, (a, b) => 
    ({ min_price: Math.min(a.min_price, b.min_price), max_price: Math.max(a.max_price, b.max_price) }), // create a new object and return it
    { min_price:min_price, max_price:max_price });
```

Comment: this mutate the `a`, how to avoid that?

Comment: @GialaJefferson  check the edit, although there will be no reason for that at all.

Comment: because I try to avoid return usage when I use arrow function